# Whitespace to the right of site in any browser

Tags: html, css, firebug, moodle

I've been trying to shake this for a while without success.

Could someone look at this in Firebug and let me know why a scrollbar appears when the browser is minimised, then subsequently displays a chunk of horizontal whitespace to the right when scrolled?

I can't locate any rogue width styles or oversized elements.

Many thanks in advance

Brian

Comment: Where is your code or are you asking something in general

Comment: Apologies, the stress has obviously gotten to me: http://lms.i-know.com/

Answer (score 0):

`.copyIMG` and `.copy` are shown as 1024 pixels wide in Chrome for me.

Could this be your issue?

Comment: Removed both, still getting the same result I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually seeing a whitespace, but skimming through, you're setting widths to 100% and then have this:

```
#page-wrapper {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
margin: 0 auto;
min-width: 775px;
width: 90%;
```

}

is that 90% conflicting possibly?